# Why won't the files in Input move to the directory Output with the prefix?

Tags: bash

This is my code here:

```
#!/bin/bash

#read in a directory

echo "Enter input directory:"

read inputDir

#lists the files in a directory

#this lists the path with the file

for entry in "$inputDir"/*

do

  echo "$entry"

        touch $entry

done

echo "Enter output directory"

read outputDir

mkdir -p $outputDir

#changing directorys will allow us to not list the path

cd $outputDir

prefix=kml_

#after changing the directory we can then move the file and add a prefix.

for entry in *

  do

  mv $entry $prefix$entry

done
```

Why wont the files I have in my input folder move to the output folder?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "because you didn't try to move them".

The longer answer is that before running the `mv` command, you change into a different folder (`cd $outputDir`) so when you run your for loop (`for entry in *`) it expands a different list of files from the ones you intended.

You could modify your code like this (original comments removed):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter input directory:"
read inputDir

for entry in "$inputDir"/*
do
    echo "$entry"
    touch "$entry" # it is unclear why you do this step
done

echo "Enter output directory"
read outputDir
mkdir -p "$outputDir"

prefix=kml_

for entry in "$inputDir"/*
do
    # strip directory
    entryNoPath=${entry##*/}           # pure bash method
    # entryNoPath=$(basename "$entry") # common alternative method

    mv $entry "$outputDir/$prefix$entryNoPath"
done
```